# flutter : Passing assetpath as a string and load asset value

Tags: string, flutter, dart, assets

I want to show text in a container by loading assets( textfile) from the asset path which I have received from another class as a string. But after running the container shows empty. I have tried this way.

assetpath String:

```
  final String assetPath = 'lib/asset/textfile/cs_one.txt';
```

class one( sending assetpath as a string ):

```
Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => cs_one( assetPath : assetPath) ),
          );
```

class two ( receiving assetpath from class one and loading data ) :

```
 class cs_one extends StatefulWidget {
 final String assetPath;
 const cs_one({Key? key, required this.assetPath}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _cs_oneState createState() => _cs_oneState( );
 }

 class _cs_oneState extends State<cs_one> {

 String? data;
  static String? get assetPath => assetPath;

void _loadData() async {
final _loadedData =
await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath!);
setState(() {
  data = _loadedData;
});
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_loadData();
}
```

Showing text in widget:

```
body:  SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        width: 360,
        child: Text(data ?? 'empty'),
      ))),
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is solved.
I solved it this way:

```
class cs_one extends StatefulWidget {
final String assetPath;
const cs_one({Key? key, required this.assetPath}) : super(key: key);

@override
_cs_oneState createState() => _cs_oneState(assetPath );
}

class _cs_oneState extends State<cs_one> {

String? data;
String path='';
_cs_oneState(String assetPath){
 this.path=assetPath;
}

void _loadData() async {
final _loadedData =
await rootBundle.loadString(path);
setState(() {
  data = _loadedData;
 });
}
```